# Sound not coming through to my headphones

Tags: sound

So test speakers does not play any sound at all.
When I adjust the volume from the same panel I hear ... .... ... , while adjusting. Brief static.

pavucontrol does not show any sound activity. Music has no sound, audacity has no sound.

During a Viber call when this first appeared I maximized my volume and the Viber "exit call" sound was perfectly replicated and it almost took my head off at max volume. This can be replicated. Any other sound in Viber is muted.

My reboot sequence sounds like it always has.

It is a USB audio device, I have tried unplugging it hot and cold.

My dmesg contains:

```
audit: type=1400 audit(1593207783.067:69): apparmor="DENIED"     
operation="open" profile="snap.viber-unofficial.viber" 
name="/proc/4173/setgroups" pid=4173 comm="Viber" 
requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```